# Graphite/Carbon not retaining data for some statistics

Tags: graphite, collectd

I have a Carbon/Graphite stack with some very basic retention schemas set up. These retention periods work fine, apart from on a couple of statistics - these only appear to last for a week.

My storage-schemas.conf:

```
[carbon]
pattern = ^carbon\.
retentions = 60:90d

[collectd]
pattern = ^collectd.*
retentions = 10s:2d,1m:14d,5m:1y
```

And my storage-aggregation.conf:

```
[min]
pattern = \.min$
xFilesFactor = 0.1
aggregationMethod = min

[max]
pattern = \.max$
xFilesFactor = 0.1
aggregationMethod = max

[sum]
pattern = \.count$
xFilesFactor = 0
aggregationMethod = sum

[default_average]
pattern = .*
xFilesFactor = 0.5
aggregationMethod = average
```

All stats arrive prefixed with collectd., so the retention patterns are correct. When viewing an affected dashboard in Grafana I see the following in graphite's cache.log:

> Thu Oct 13 11:25:16 2016 :: CarbonLink cache-query request for collectd.host_domain_com.openstack-keystone-totals.gauge-users-count returned 0 datapoints

Using whisper-info.py on an affected .wsp shows the following:

```
maxRetention: 31536000
xFilesFactor: 0.5
aggregationMethod: average
fileSize: 1710772

Archive 0
retention: 172800
secondsPerPoint: 10
points: 17280
size: 207360
offset: 52

Archive 1
retention: 1209600
secondsPerPoint: 60
points: 20160
size: 241920
offset: 207412

Archive 2
retention: 31536000
secondsPerPoint: 300
points: 105120
size: 1261440
offset: 449332
```

Can anyone suggest anything I may have missed?

Answer (score 0):

So the answer to this comes from a couple of issues. Firstly, the data points are being submitted with -count on the end of the name instead of .count, so the default [sum] aggregation is being applied to the data. Because we're not submitting data every 10 seconds (and because we have an xFilesFactor of 0.5 on the default), the data is munged when it hits the retention point and because there are less than 50% of the expected data points, a null value is stored instead.